# Unmet dependencies ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

I've recently shifted from windows to ubuntu and it doesnt seem to be a smooth start.
I've installed Ubuntu 20.04.
Everytime I try to install a package,I get this following error:

somal@Creator:~$ sudo apt-get install nodejs

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcrypt1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not going to be installed
 libgcc-s1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 libgcrypt20:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not going to be installed
 libgpg-error0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.28) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: libgpg-error-l10n:i386
 libidn2-0:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 liblz4-1:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
 liblzma5:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
 libunistring2:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
 nodejs : Depends: libnode64 (= 10.19.0~dfsg-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: nodejs-doc but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've tried solving using the askubuntu forum and stackexchange forum.Nothing works

Comment: Edit your question above to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt --fix-broken install`?